# Redux saga not working after network reconnection

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Using redux saga to handle async requests. I noticed that if the user lost its network connection and execute the action, the saga will handle it on the catch block but when after while the network reconnects, sagas stop work because the function generator don't executes anymore. And just back to work again if the user refresh the page. Thats not good for ux.

I appreciate if anybody can give me a hand.

**action**:

```
export function sendMessage(room, message) {
return {
    type: 'SEND_MESSAGE',
    payload: {
        room,
        message,
    },
}}
```

**saga:**

```
function* sendMessage({ payload: { room, message } }) {
   yield api.sendMessage(room, message);
} catch (error) {
  /* code... */
}}

export default all([
   takeLatest('SEND_MESSAGE', sendMessage),
]);
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What's the wrong behavior? What error message you've seen? Please, fill in more details so that people can help.

Comment: If make a dispatch and because i dont have connection the catch block handles it. But when the network reconnects the function generator from saga don't fire anymore. Just fire again when refresh the page.

Comment: I see why now. It’s because your root saga crashes after disconnect. And it won’t recover magically after reconnect. Read [the doc](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga#keeping-the-root-alive) carefully.

Comment: You mention that the catch block is invoked, but never show us how you actually handle the error. If you don’t handle the error properly and recover from abnormality, then there’s no point catching it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you @hackape  Handling the error properly in the catch block solved the issue